# Synonymize "crockpot" tag to "slow-cooker"? (It's a bit complicated)

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Crock-Pot is the brand name of a particular manufacturer of slow cooker. We shouldn't be using the brand name in our tags since only people familiar with that specific brand will be able to find the correct tag.

Unfortunately, we've got the [slow-cooker](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/slow-cooker) tag synonymized to another tag, [slow-cooking](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/slow-cooking), which is **not**, specifically about using a slow cooker to prepare food.

> Questions around slower, normally lower temperature cooking methods. Covers preparations, techniques, risks, advantages and equipment.

This is ambiguous enough to cover slow-roasting and smoking - maybe even sous-vide and stewing (on a stovetop), for example.

I'm not really sure what the best solution here is. If we want slow cooking to be more generic, fine, but we should remove the synonym so that we can make [crockpot](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crockpot) a synonym of [slow-cooker](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/slow-cooker) and have that be specifically about self-contained cooking units as defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slow_cooker).

Alternately, if slow-cooking is just about cooking in a slow cooker, we can clarify that in the tag description (we do already have tags for roasting and smoking and sous vide) and leave the current synonym.

There are a bit over 200 questions tagged with [slow-cooking](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/slow-cooking) and only about 80 with [crockpot](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crockpot).

Also, "crockpot" is just wrong, in general. The brand name is "Crock-Pot".

Comment: Maybe someone could go through a sample of the [tag:slow-cooking] questions and see what fraction are slow cooker questions, as opposed to roasting, smoking, or sous vide? Clarifying and leaving the synonym is probably only a good option if it's already mostly about slow cookers.

Comment: Out of the first 30 questions on the slow-cooking tag, only one is for slow-cooking methods that are not a slow cooker/crockpot.  So I'd say it's fine to keep slow-cooking as a synonym to slow-cooker.

Comment: To me a smoker is a slow cooker also.  There is no smoker tag.  I have an enameled metal slow cooker I would not call a crock-pot.

Answer (score 2):

Based on actual usage on the site, "slow cooking", "slow cooker" and "crockpot" should all be synonyms.  If folks want to discuss other methods of cooking slowly, I'd recommend the "sous vide", and/or "barbeque" tags.

Comment: While basically agreeing with you, I'm not sure a question like "what oven temperature for a stew to be cooked over 7 hours?" (hypothetical example) could be tagged with anything better than "slow-cooking"

Comment: It's not 100%.  But out of the last 30 items for that tag, 26 of them are definitely for crockpots, and 3 are unclear, leaving only 1 being about *not* crockpots.

Comment: @ChrisH We actually have a tag for [tag:stews]. I don't think that, in that case, "slow cooking" would be necessary.